# Sending and deleting records to database with a drag and drop table

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli, drag-and-drop

I have three db tables.

-Paid

-Partially Paid

-Owes

When someone registers for an account I send their user_id, name, etc to my 'Owes' db table and then output their name into a drag and drop table I have in the 'Owes' column. As of now if I move anyone's name to any other category (Paid/Partially paid) I am not sure how to delete that record from the Owes db and insert the name into the new db table so the changes are permanent.

What's really throwing me off is how to do it with the drag and drop table. I'm not sure how to apply the logic that when something is dropped into that column that the past record is deleted and a new one is added to that specific table or how to make the changes without a submit button or page reload.

What is a way I can do this and how could I structure it?

PHP

```
<?php
//Payment Section

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
    $paid_run = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM paid ORDER BY id DESC");
    $partially_paid_run = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM partial_payment ORDER BY id DESC");
    $owes_run = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM owes ORDER BY id DESC");
    $paid_numrows = mysqli_num_rows($paid_run);
    $partially_paid_numrows = mysqli_num_rows($partially_paid_run);
    $owes_numrows = mysqli_num_rows($owes_run);

        if($paid_numrows > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($paid_run)){
                $paid_id = $row['user_id'];
                $paid_name = $row['name'];
            }
        }

    if($partially_paid_numrows > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($partially_paid_run)){
                $partially_paid_id = $row['user_id'];
                $partially_paid_name = $row['name'];
                $partially_paid_amount = $row['payment'];
            }
        }

    if($owes_numrows > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($owes_run)){
                $owes_id = $row['user_id'];
                $owes_name = $row['name'];
            }
        }
?>  
$(function() {
    $( "#paid, #partially_paid, #owes" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".tdPayment",
      remove: function(e, ui) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var childs = $this.find('div');
        if (childs.length === 0) {
           $this.text("Nothing");
        }
      },
      receive: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).contents().filter(function() {
            return this.nodeType == 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
         }).remove();
      },
    }).disableSelection();
  });
```

Table

```
<table class="paymentTable" id="dragTable">
        <tr>
            <th class="thPayment">Paid</th>
            <th class="thPayment">Partially Paid</th>
            <th class="thPayment">Owes</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tdPayment" id="paid">
                            <div>
            <?php
                if ($paid_name == true) {
                    echo $paid_name;
                } else {
                    echo "No one has paid";
                }
            ?>
                            </div>
            </td>
            <td class="tdPayment" id="partially_paid">
            <div>
            <?php 
                if ($partially_paid__name == true) {
                    echo $partially_paid__name . " - " . $partially_paid_amount;
                } else {
                    echo "No one has made a partial payment";
                }
            ?>  
            </div>
            </td>
            <td class="tdPayment" id="owes">
            <div>
            <?php
                if ($owes_name == true) {
                    echo $owes_name;
                } else {
                    echo "Everyone has paid something";
                }
            ?>  
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough outline on how to do it. I would recommend using jQuery, a JavaScript library that has a lot of useful stuff for this.

1. Implement the drag and drop part using jQuery [draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/). A nice guide can be found [here](http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/).
2. Write a PHP page that updates the database the way you want it.
3. Use jQuery to call that page when something is dropped. This can be done using [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

**Clarification of part 3**

I recommend looking at the [photo manager](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager) in the droppable documentation to get a full working example of something similar.

For this to work, you need to set up the HTML so it has some class names and some data attributes:

```
<h1>Owes</h1>
<div class="bin" data-bin-id="1">
  <div class="user" data-user-id="5">Eva</a>
  <div class="user" data-user-id="8">Anna</a>
</div>

<h1>Partially paid</h1>
<div class="bin" data-bin-id="2">
  <div class="user" data-user-id="2">Tom</a>
  ...
</div>

...
```

Then we need to implement some javascript that takes care of calling the PHP when the user drops something:

```
jQuery(".bin").droppable({
  accept: ".user",
  drop: function( event, ui ) {

    //Get the ID of the bin the user was dropped into.
    var intBinID = jQuery(this).attr("data-bin-id");

    //Get the ID of the user that was dropped.
    var intUserID = ui.droppable.attr("data-user-id");

    //Make an ajax call to the PHP page.
    jQuery.ajax("update.php?binid=" + intBinID + "&userid=" + intUserID);

  }
});
```

In addition you might want update.php to return something to let the JavaScript know if it worked or not, and if it failed abort the drop.

***Disclaimar:*** Since I don't have all the parts of this project set up, I have not tested this code.

Comment: I have Step 1 done, Step 2 I can have done pretty easily. I just don't know how to integrate the actions I do with the drag and drop table to the update the db. I am not sure of how, if I move someone's name from the Owes to Paid column, how the scripts will recognize the name went into that column and then how that column represents what I actually am wanting it to represent.

Comment: Thanks for really giving me a good start. This helps a bunch. I have one question though. How can I assisgn a data-user-id when the name are going to be outputted from my database through a while loop. I could have 5 names one day and then 5 people could register and then I'd have 10. These names will not be static code.

Comment: You will have to generate the HTML code with PHP. Query the database for the users, and then loop through the result and do something like `echo '<div class="user" data-user-id="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</div>';`. [Here](http://codular.com/php-mysqli) is a good intro on MySQLi that will help you do it.

Comment: Gotcha... I didn't know if the Jquery could have pulled that. I have a variable assigned for the user_id already. $paid_id = $row['user_id']; ... I appreciate your help. I'll try this out and see how it goes!

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to do this, is by creating an independent User table where you keep all the users. Then, in a separate table like the ones you have already, you just keep the Id of that user (and maybe some information related to how much he owes or has already payed).
This way, when you have to insert or to update any information about the state of the user, you just have to insert/delete the Id of the User from these tables.

The information about the user will always be safe and kept in it's own table.

Comment: That is what I am doing now. I have a separate users table and then I am only sending over the user_id to these other three separate db tables. I just do not know how to do this with the drag and drop method.

Comment: It should also be added that it would be a good idea no to keep three separate tables for their payment status, but one with a column called `PAYMENT_STATUS` that you set to `1` for owes, `2` for partially paid and `3` for paid or something like that. That means that instead of doing one `DELETE` and one `INSERT` you just make one `UPDATE`.

Comment: Do you know how I could make this work with the drag and drop table?

Comment: With a drag and drop table in a webpage you can just do ajax post's to update the database info.
After the changes are made you do a final select to get the new listings of the drag and drop tables to show to the user.